# How to update python version with pyenv (update python 3.6.2 to 3.6.5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyenv

I would like to update python version 3.6.2 to 3.6.5 using pyenv.

Do I need to first pyenv install 3.6.5 and then install my packages that are currently in my 3.6.2 version? And then, if I wanted to, pyenv uninstall 3.6.2?

Any help would be appreciated!